# Error installing RSAT on Windows 8.1: "This update is not applicable to your computer"

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I am trying to install the [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972). When I run the installer, I get the following error:

"The update is not applicable to your computer."

[image: screenshot of error message]

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The version of the tool you are trying to install only supports **Windows 8.0**

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296) is the correct version of the tool which supports **Windows 8.1**

Here are the requirements for the version you attempted to install:

> **Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8 can be installed ONLY on computers that are running Windows 8.** Remote Server
>   Administration Tools cannot be installed on computers with an Advanced
>   RISC Machine (ARM) architecture, or other system-on-chip devices.

Here are the requirements for the version you should install:

> **Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8.1 can be installed ONLY on computers that are running full releases of Windows 8.1 Pro or
>   Windows 8.1 Enterprise.** Remote Server Administration Tools cannot be
>   installed on Windows RT, computers with an Advanced RISC Machine (ARM)
>   architecture, or other system-on-chip devices. Remote Server
>   Administration Tools for Windows 8.1 also cannot be installed on
>   prerelease or evaluation copies of Windows 8.1.

The following requirements are shared between the two versions just exchange the 8.1 for 8.0.

> Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8.1 is available in the
>   following languages: cs-CZ, de-DE, en-US, es-ES, fr-FR, hu-HU, it-IT,
>   ja-JP, ko-KR, nl-NL, pl-PL, pt-BR, pt-PT, ru-RU, sv-SE, tr-TR, zh-CN,
>   zh-HK, and zh-TW. If the system UI language of your Windows 8.1
>   operating system does not match any of the available RSAT languages,
>   you must first install a Windows 8.1 Language Pack for a language that
>   is supported by RSAT, and then try installing Remote Server
>   Administration Tools for Windows 8.1 again.
>
> IMPORTANT: Remove all older versions of Administration Tools Pack or
>   Remote Server Administration Tools—including older prerelease
>   versions, and releases of the tools for different languages or
>   locales—from the computer before you install Remote Server
>   Administration Tools for Windows 8.1. Only one copy at a time of
>   Remote Server Administration Tools can be installed on a computer. If
>   you have upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 7, you will need to
>   install Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8.1 on the
>   computer; no earlier releases of Remote Server Administration Tools
>   are still installed on a computer that you have upgraded to Windows
>   8.1.

Comment: That would explain it. I'll try with that version.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a somewhat common problem.  Technet has lots of people complaining of the same problem.

First, ensure that you are trying to install the correct RSAT version: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39296

The workarount that most people seem to have suggested (which are reported as working) is run the following as an admin in cmd.exe:

```
dism.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:windows8.1-KB2693643-x64.cab
```

Failing this, someone has mentioned an in-place upgrade from professional to professional.. no idea why, but it seemed to work.

Failing that, and I have no idea why they mention Vista in the code, but try:

1. Extract the contents of the .MSU file using the following command:
   '`expand -f:* "Vista 32-bit.msu" C:\Temp`'
   This extracted the msu file and we got the .CAB file.
2. Installed the .CAB file using package manager utility. We used the following
   command:
   '`pkgmgr.exe /ip /m:"path\package_name.CAB`"'

Note: I have no idea why they all mention

Comment: using DISM is not forcing the install.  Also, the expand and pkgmgr version is just an alternative incase it still doesn't work.  If you had read my answer properly, you would have noticed that the "wrong version" issue was also addressed alongside other options

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows service **Windows Update** and make sure it's started.

How to start a Microsoft Windows Service.

1. Go to start/Run
2. Type Services.msc and press `enter`
3. Search for Windows Update Service
4. Start the service
5. Now install RSAT

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the right version as your operating system. either 32 or 64 bit, if the version is right go to control panel , click view installed updates then check for Remote server administrative tools and uncheck, it should now work